Radar signal processing
I have a set of measurement data on which I want to apply blind source separation to separate mixed signals. But the no.of source is unknown and the measurement consists of 4 channels and 1000 range gates in each of the channels.
I am using this code (given below) to compute fastica, since I have no idea about the no.of sources, so I am not sure what value to use under n_components. If I keep n_components as None, then the no.of elements in S comes out be the no.of range gates that I use at the input. Can anyone suggest how to do it correctly?
The code that I have tried is given below
def complex_FastICA(X,epsilon=.1,algorithm='parallel',\
                    max_iter=100,tol=1e-4,whiten=True,\
                    w_init=None,n_components=None):
    """Performs Fast Independent Component Analysis of complex-valued 
        signals

    Parameters
    ----------

    X : array, shape (n_features,n_samples)
        Input signal X = A S, where A is the mixing 
        matrix and S the latent sources.

    epsilon : float, optional
        Arbitrary constant in the contrast G function 
        used in the approximation to neg-entropy.

    algorithm : {'parallel', 'deflation'}, optional
        Apply a parallel or deflational FASTICA algorithm.

    w_init : (n_components, n_components) array, optional
        Initial un-mixing array.If None (default) then an 
        array of normally distributed r.v.s is used.

    tol: float, optional
        A positive scalar giving the tolerance at which the
        un-mixing matrix is considered to have converged.

    max_iter : int, optional
        Maximum number of iterations.
    
    whiten : boolean, optional
        If True, perform an initial whitening of the data.
        If False, the data is assumed to be already white.

    n_components : int, optional
        Number of components to extract. If None, 
        n_components = n_features.

    Returns
    -------

    W : array, shape (n_components, n_components)
        Estimated un-mixing matrix.

    K : array, shape (n_components, n_features)
        If whiten is 'True', K is the pre-whitening matrix 
        projecting the data onto the principal components. 
        If whiten is 'False', K is 'None'.

    EG : array, shape(n_components,max_iter)
        Expectation of the contrast function E[G(|W'*X|^2)]. 
        This array may be padded with NaNs at the end.

    S : array, shape (n_samples, n_components)
        Estimated sources (S = W K X).
    """

    n,m  = X.shape
    
    if n_components!=None:
        n = n_components

    if whiten:
        X-=X.mean(1,keepdims=True)
        Ux,Sx = eig(np.cov(X))
        K     = np.sqrt(inv(np.diag(Ux))).dot(Sx.conj().T)[:n]
        X     = K.dot(X)
        del Ux,Sx
    else:
        K = None

    EG = np.ones((n,max_iter))*np.nan

    if algorithm=='deflation':

        W = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=complex)

        for k in range(n):
            if w_init!=None:
                w = w_init[:,k]
            else:
                w = np.random.normal(size=(n,1))+\
                    1j*np.random.normal(size=(n,1))

            w/=norm(w)

            n_iter  = 0

            for i in range(max_iter):

                wold = np.copy(w)

                #derivative of the contrast function
                g  =  1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(w,X))
                #derivative of g
                dg = -1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(w,X))**2

                w  = (X * (w.conj().T.dot(X)).conj() * g).mean(1).reshape((n,1))-\
                     (g + abs_sqr(w,X) * dg).mean() * w

                del g,dg

                w/=norm(w)

                # Decorrelation
                w-=W.dot(W.conj().T).dot(w)
                w/=norm(w)

                EG[k,n_iter] = (np.log(epsilon+abs_sqr(w,X))).mean()

                n_iter+=1

                lim = (abs(abs(wold)-abs(w))).sum()
                if lim<tol:
                    break

            if n_iter==max_iter and lim>tol:
                warnings.warn('FastICA did not converge. Consider increasing '
                              'tolerance or the maximum number of iterations.')

            W[:,k] = w.ravel()

    elif algorithm=='parallel':

        if w_init!=None:
            W = w_init
        else:
            W = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))+\
                1j*np.random.normal(size=(n,n))

        n_iter = 0

        #cache the covariance matrix
        C = np.cov(X)

        for i in range(max_iter):

            Wold = np.copy(W)

            for j in range(n):

                #derivative of the contrast function
                g  =  (1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(W[:,j],X))).reshape((1,m))
                #derivative of g
                dg = -(1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(W[:,j],X))**2).reshape((1,m))

                W[:,j]  = (X * (W[:,j].conj().T.dot(X)).conj() * g).mean(1)-\
                          (g + abs_sqr(W[:,j],X) * dg).mean() * W[:,j]
                del g,dg

            # Symmetric decorrelation
            Uw,Sw = eig(W.conj().T.dot(C.dot(W)))
            W     = W.dot(Sw.dot(inv(np.sqrt(np.diag(Uw))).dot(Sw.conj().T)))
            del Uw,Sw

            EG[:,n_iter] = (np.log(epsilon+abs_sqr(W,X))).mean(1)

            n_iter+=1

            lim = (abs(abs(Wold)-abs(W))).sum()
            if lim < tol:
                break

        if n_iter==max_iter and lim>tol:
            warnings.warn('FastICA did not converge. Consider increasing '
                          'tolerance or the maximum number of iterations.')

    S = W.conj().T.dot(X)

    return K,W,S,EG


maybe take this to the [dsp.se] SE
